# Sample rate and note frequences

Tags: c++, arduino

How is it possible to play hi frequences notes with 44100 sample rate

For example 
If we try to create 2959.95538169307680 hz F#7  wave at sample rate 44100 then one cicle must be defined by 13 samples (sampleRate / hz) 
The problem is if we take next note 3135.96348785399680 G7 hz then this will be also 13 samples due to convertion from decimal to int.

It seems that it is impossible to generate accruate notes above 7 octave with 44100 sample rate? Or is there some trick?

Samples -> Hz

13         2959.95538169307680 F#7

13         3135.96348785399680 G7

Comment: The trick is to not round to an integer.

Comment: whell then it is not 44100 sample rate any more but analog signal

Comment: Think about it the other way round - what if you played an "analog" G7, and then sampled it digitally?  What would the samples look like?

Comment: @Woland: the *step* with which you select a sample should not be integral (of course you should round or truncate it before accessing the sample). The *rate* is still 44.1k. There have been entire books written about this, BTW. Take a look at the subject of digital signal processing.

Comment: FWIW, generally, you have many more samples, e.g. 4096 values of a sine wave. Then you step over those with different step sizes (usually these are not integers!), depending on the frequency and sampling rate. For the frequency you mention, this will pick 13 or 14 samples, but not always exactly the same ones per cycle. If you want to do this right and to avoid overtones, you should also have several wavetables for different frequency ranges, each filtered differently to rule out aliasing. This is a rather complex subject and not easily answered in an SO answer.

Comment: Thanks guys I finaly get it.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that it is impossible to generate accruate notes above 7 octave with 44100 sample rate

With 44100 sample rate per second, you can surely create sounds up to 22Khz, which means you can create sounds of entire human hearing range,

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate

What do you mean by creating it in 13 cycles? note that the notes (or frequencies) you are considering are irrational numbers, so not repeating itself in 13 cycles. They will not repeat themselves in many thousands bit length signal sequence. (consider it like the number pi)

Comment: 44100 Hz sampling equals 22,675736961 microseconds. To create 2959.95538169307680 hz F#7, you need period of 337,842930399 microseconds. which equals 14,898873231 sampling period. For 3135.96348785399680 hz G7, you need a periof of 318,881263724 seconds. which is 14,062663731 sampling period. So, let me clear myself, for F#7, create a loop, which toggles the output once in every 14.89... / 2 = 7,449436615 samples and for G7, create a loop which toggles the output once in every 14,06../2 = 7,031331866 samples. Such arrangements without FFT etc sounds artificial, as lacking overtones.

Answer (score 0):

A sample rate of 44.1k means that you can only generate notes of at most 22.05k (this is the so-called [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency)). You generally use a [wavetable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavetable_synthesis) that is more than 13 samples, say, 256 or 1024 or even larger (in my synth, I use 4096 32 bit samples per waveform).

Say you have an array with 1024 values of a sinus wave. Then, to generate a frequency of, say, 3000 Hz, you will step through this array with a step of 1024*3000.0/44100.0 = 69.65986. So you start at index 0, then the next will be the sample at index 69, then the next at index (int)2*69.65986 = 139, the next at (int)3*step, etc. If you reach the end of the array, you wrap around to the beginning, constantly adding the step you calculated for the given frequency.

Doing it that way, this will pick 13 or 14 samples out of the 1024 in the array, but not the same ones on each cycle.

If you want to do this without creating overtones, you may have to use oversampling and to generate different wavetables for different frequency ranges, where the ones for high frequencies are filtered (e.g. using an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform), removing frequencies above Nyquist and then doing a reverse FFT) to remove overtones.

This is not a simple subject. But just having a table of 13 samples will not be enough. That will not sound right, and you can't reliably produce a proper frequency, as you already noted.

There is *a lot* of material on digital signal processing (and generating) on the web. Discussing it in depth is not possible in a simple Q&A medium like this.